# Minecraft accounts linked

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Son and Daughter have separate Minecraft accounts and each have their own iPads. However they started with both using a single iPad. They both have Xbox accounts and play in each others worlds as they are both on the same Wifi. However, my daughter just lost all her packs for the second time and they seem to have transferred over to my sons account despite them both having separate accounts. The only change recently was that she signed up for the Realms Plus trial and invited him to play in those worlds. It appears that both accounts are linked but i cant find how.

I have tried backing up her worlds, deleting Minecraft and reinstalling it but she has lost her packs since then.

Can anyone advise how to check if 2 accounts are linked and how to unlink them. I tried Mojang and while helpful they just pass me back to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accounts are liked, but instead I thing that your problem is that when someone joins a realm with active pack they will have to download said packs. if this is the case it means your son had to download the packs (for free, don't worry) when he joined the realm. In which case your daughters packs have just been victim to a glitch.
I am just speculating so don't believe what i have said to be fact.

Comment: Thanks Fixb, I think you are correct (although I know nothing about Minecraft :-) ). She bought the packs before trying Realms and he most probably downloaded them for free when he payed in her Realm?? 

I have had lengthy discussions with Mojang support and they best they could suggest it to talk to Microsoft which is a complete waste of time. I got absolutely nowhere with them and i feel the only solution at this stage is to tell them to stop playing the game or stop buying packs unfortunately.